# add column in query on Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

On the Firebird 2.5 server DB has tables: goods, income, sale.
Goods table has columns: goods_id, name
Income:  Income_id,Goods_id,incomeqty(quantity),recdate
Sale:  sales_id,income_id,Goods_id,saleqty,recdate

I have query that selects incomes, sales and differences between them in date intervals and it works correctly:

```
select income.goods_id,
  sum(case when which = 'income' then sum_amt else 0 end) as sum_income,
  sum(case when which = 'sale' then sum_amt else 0 end) as sum_sale,
  sum(case when which = 'income' then sum_amt else 0 end)
  - sum(case when which = 'sale' then sum_amt else 0 end) as differ_between
from (select goods_id, sum(incomeqty) as sum_amt, 'income' as which
     from income
    where income.recdate betwwen :d1 and :d2         
    group by pr_k
   union all
   select goods_id, sum(salesqty), 'sale'
     from sales
     where sale.recdate between :d1 and :d2 
    group by goods_id) x
group by goods_id
```

but I want additionally select goods names from goods table. How include  "name" column  and if clause("where goods_id=income.goods_id" ) in this query?

Answer (score 1):

Simple add join

```
select x.goods_id, G.name,
  sum(case when which = 'income' then sum_amt else 0 end) as sum_income,
  sum(case when which = 'sale' then sum_amt else 0 end) as sum_sale,
  sum(case when which = 'income' then sum_amt else 0 end)
 - sum(case when which = 'sale' then sum_amt else 0 end) as differ_between
from (select goods_id, sum(incomeqty) as sum_amt, 'income' as which
     from income
    where income.recdate betwwen :d1 and :d2         
    group by pr_k
   union all
   select goods_id, sum(salesqty), 'sale'
     from sales
     where sale.recdate between :d1 and :d2 
    group by goods_id) x 
    INNER JOIN GOODS G ON G.goods_id=x.goods_id
group by x.goods_id, G.name
```

but i do not know how your posted query work "select income.goods_id" if income is not included?

**Modified version to support your comment**

```
select x.goods_id, G.name,
  sum(case when which = 'income' then sum_amt else 0 end) as sum_income,
  sum(case when which = 'sale' then sum_amt else 0 end) as sum_sale,
  sum(case when which = 'income' then sum_amt else 0 end)
 - sum(case when which = 'sale' then sum_amt else 0 end) as differ_between
from 
    GOODS G LEFT JOIN
    (select goods_id, sum(incomeqty) as sum_amt, 'income' as which
     from income
    where income.recdate betwwen :d1 and :d2         
    group by pr_k
   union all
   select goods_id, sum(salesqty), 'sale'
     from sales
     where sale.recdate between :d1 and :d2 
    group by goods_id) x ON G.goods_id=x.goods_id
group by x.goods_id, G.name
```

but i suppose better then will be changing order of fields in "group by" and "select" to:

```
select G.name, x.goods_id ...
....
group by G.name, x.goods_id ...
```

Comment: **Livius**  with Inner Join it works but if there are no data in datetime  interval then goods name not appear in DBGrid. How to change query so that all goods names always were appear despite the fact that incomes and sales are were or not in this datetime interval.
I change Inner Join with Left Join but nothing changed.

Comment: See a modified version if it meets these requirements

Comment: As I realized I must select G.goods_id and not x.goods_id in select operator. I changed select x.goods_id... with select G.goods_id... and it works perfectly. 
thank you Livius.